# How to install flush mount lights when ceiling electrical box is 1/4 of an inch below sheetrock?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling

We recently bought a house and are changing the lights. The ones that are currently installed have a dome base. We bought ones that will sit flush. The issues is that some of the electrical boxes hang down up to 1/4 of an inch below the ceiling. This causes the new light to not sit flush.

What options do we have?

Comment: How big of an area is this, are all lights in one room, picture would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

1. Put back the old light fixtures.
2. Convert some of the new fixtures to the dome type base.
3. Access the electrical boxes and remount them.
4. Rip out the old boxes and install new boxes in the correct alignment.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difficulty level between 3 and 4? Will either 3 or 4 require being in the attic or can it be done from below? Advantages or disadvantage for 3 or 4?

Comment: Work with 3 is possibly less than 4. It depends a great deal upon how the existing box is attached to the ceiling structure. If it is mounted in a way that does not require removal of all the electrical wires from the box then it would be easier to do 3. On the other hand if the wiring is very old and pre-dates the modern style of ROMEX wiring you may actually want to try to make 3 work for you because you may need to avoid removing the wires from the existing box. Option 4 obviously involves removing the wires from the existing box. Access to the space above the ceiling (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) is most likely required. The alternative is to open up the ceiling around the box so that you can work through the hole to relocate the box. Once again a lot depends upon how the box is currently secured in place. Once you dig into how the protruding boxes are mounted you could take some photos (both above and below the ceiling) come back here with another question. There are a few good tricks that can be used to re-mount boxes that we could share with you if we were able to evaluate just how your situation looks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The one box was centered between the trusses hanging from a rod. I was able to prop this up (short piece of wood between the sheetrock and metal rod) just a little bit and that one is good. Some of the others will need pried off the truss and re-nailed. Thanks again!